# Local notifications in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, windows-phone, localnotification, xamarin.forms

Does windows phone 8 have anything like Local Notifications in android?
If not, how can we add an item to `system tray` list?!
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for local notifications in windows phone 8 :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207047(v=vs.105).aspx